# How replace jade by html

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm using the express skelton to develope an app. I don't know how to use jade language, so I want to convert this files to html, I did that, but my problem now it's I have 2 lines the aim js : app.js that have to change

```
// view engine setup            
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));         
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Please can you help me to change this lines, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use EJS(http://embeddedjs.com/) as a view engine and use the html (in form of ejs files)

```
`app.set('view engine', 'ejs');`
```

and place the .ejs files containing the html code within the view folder.

You'll have to update the dependencies in the package.json as well

```
"ejs": ">= 0.0.0"
```

For listing static html pages, use this property in express

```
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`
```

and place your .html files within the public folder.